# Spring boot + LDAP form login, logout and validating the token after login

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-security, ldap

I am integrating spring boot with LDAP to Authenticate a user. So that only authenticated users can only access the API.

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    LdapAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(final LdapAuthenticator authenticator) {
        return new LdapAuthenticationProvider(authenticator);
    }

    @Bean
    BindAuthenticator authenticator(final BaseLdapPathContextSource contextSource) {
        final BindAuthenticator authenticator = new BindAuthenticator(contextSource);
        authenticator.setUserDnPatterns(new String[] {
                "xx" });
        return authenticator;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication().userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")
        .contextSource(contextSource());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf()
        .disable()
                .formLogin().and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.debug(true);
    }

    @Bean
    LdapContextSource contextSource() {
        final LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl("xx);
        contextSource.setBase("xx");
        contextSource.setUserDn("xx");
        contextSource.setPassword("xx");
        contextSource.setPooled(true);
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        return contextSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
        final LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(
            contextSource());
        ldapTemplate.setIgnorePartialResultException(true);
        return ldapTemplate;
    }

}
```

I am using the inbuild form login.

Question

1. Who (which class) is responsible to create a success token and where is it stored and in successive calls how is it validated?
2. Now I am only redirecting the unauthenticated calls to the login page due to this it giving 200 success responses, How to override this and send 401

Edited:
I have one specific question
If there is no token, the user is stored in the session ->  how subsequent requests are validated. Which all classes are used

Comment: 1. There is no token, user is stored in the session, 2. is the default, if you want only a 401 (why you are using form based login anyway) you need to configure it as such.

Comment: @M.Deinum 2-> What is the best practice ..?  I want my API to be only accessed by authenticated users only.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have one specific question 
  There is no token, the user is stored in the session ->  how subsequent requests are validated.

Comment: The user is retrieved from the session. This is a regular HTTP session for which a session cookie is send.